# Background-image vs. input type text how to set size

Tags: html, css

Why my background can't fit input?

Here is my html code:

```
<input type="text" class="background"/>
```

and some css:

```
.background {
  background-image: url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-check-icon.png");
  bacground-size:  100%;
}
```

Here is [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bZQVkp) as well

Comment: First you have a spelling error. its `background-size`. It may be related to the fact you didn't specify `background-size: cover;`. Let me know if any of these work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `background-size` to `100% 100%`, `background-position` to `50%`, `background-repeat` to `no-repeat`

```css
.background {
  background-image: url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-check-icon.png");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-position: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="background" />
```

codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xOQkbQ